# Remap Top-Row Number Keys

Tags: macos, keyboard

I've tried Ukulele and KeyRemap4MacBook. Neither does what I need to do.

I want to map the top-row <kbd>4</kbd> key and the top-row <kbd>8</kbd> key to <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>. So that, for example, when I press <kbd>4</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> it types a capital G.

Hitting the shift key with my pinkie is aggravating my carpal tunnel. On my windows machine I just remapped <kbd>4</kbd> and <kbd>8</kbd> to shift and I use a keypad if I need numbers. Savior for my hands.

Comment: Wow this is quite a question. Let's see if people can solve this...

Answer (score 1):

Ukelele should be able to kind of do this by making 4 a "deadkey" that generates the uppercase letter for any key typed after it, unless there is a limit on the number of keys you can have in such a sequence.  (Just like alt + e is a deadkey that generates acute accented versions of any vowel typed after it)

Of course this is not exactly like Shift, because you can't hold it down, you have let 4 go before you hit the next letter.

Comment: I've done something similar with my current keyboard layout, but there are obviously some additional issues. You'll still have to use the actual shift keys with keyboard shortcuts. And it won't work in virtualized environments. And for example dead key sequences don't enter table cell editing mode in iWork apps.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar with [Karabiner Elements](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/). Left and right shift are in the dropdown menu.

[image]

(For the record, after doing this I remapped the Function keys to number keys, so that that functionality is not lost!  You get all the shifted symbols on the Function keys as well, e.g.,  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> gives <kbd>!</kbd>)